# 'Building' has encountered a problem. An internal error occurred during. "Building"

Tags: robotframework

I tried to create a Robot project , but I am getting this error : An internal error occurred during: "Building".
Unable to communicate with XML-RPC server
I tried some solution , but didn't work , and now when I press OK , I can't access to the libraries and the files inside the projects...[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KcmGU.png)

My installation is:
Eclipse  2021-06 (4.20.0)
RED - Robot Editor 0.9.5.202007241017
Robot Framework 5.0 (Python 3.10.4 )

Answer (score 1):

you need to downgrade the Robotframework to version 3 and lower, you can do that using that command

```
pip install robotframework==3.1.1 <version>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check comparability of RED Editor and the Robot Framework. I think, RED doesn't support latest RF version. Check more: http://nokia.github.io/RED/help/whats_new/0_9_5.html
Also, check the URL that eclipse trying to communicate inside Help>>Available Software to update/install new software.