# When created a robot project getting build error

Tags: robotframework

Getting the below error when create a new project

"An internal error occurred during: 'Building'.

Unable to communicate with XML-RPC server".

All the System libraries are showing as non-accessible.

please help me in resolving this issue.

[image: pop-up]

[image: project_eclipse]

Comment: Either of the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71614288/building-has-encountered-a-problem-an-internal-error-occurred-during-buildi?rq=2) help you?